# Adjusted Chi-squared test

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am analysing questionnaire data with R and testing whether different metadata explains differences in the answers. I use chi-squared test for that. I show here two examples, where the question is which pet person has and I am analysing whether people from different countries and different professions answer differently to the question:

```
 tab <- matrix(c(7, 5, 14, 19, 3, 2, 17, 6, 12), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('dog','cat','rabbit')
rownames(tab) <- c('Italy','Greece','Hungary')
tab <- as.table(tab)
tab
chisq.test(tab)

tab2 <- matrix(c(9, 8, 12, 18, 1, 5, 16, 5, 11), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab2) <- c('dog','cat','rabbit')
rownames(tab2) <- c('Nurse','Technician','Teacher')
tab2 <- as.table(tab2)
tab2
chisq.test(tab2)
```

However, I know that that the "country" and "profession" are not independent, and there is indeed a statistically significant correlation. My question is, how could I do some kind of adjusted Chi-squared test, to test correlation of country and profession with the answers independently of each other? Or how would you handle the data?

Comment: If by "independent" you mean that people from certain countries tend to have certain type of professions, which is country specific, then this would be a classical example of testing whether profession is differently distributed among the countries using a chi square test. Is there another issue you see here?

Comment: Yes exactly, I know that profession is differentially distributed among the countries. But I want to analyse whether answers are differentially distributed among countries and whether answers are differentially distributed among professions. However, the results for countries are confounded by professions and vice versa, and this is what I want to handle.

Comment: In that case a chi square won't do, it's hypothesis is relatively simple. You may need a Poisson regression model, where you can add these confounders - if sensible - to test more precise hypothesis.